# Owl Carousel Disappears When You View In Mobile

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am using the owl carousel framework and for some odd reason i can't figure out why the carousel disappears when i enter a mobile view. I first figured that the opacity had something to do with it and when i changed that it didn't do anything. Here is the snippet that i believe is causing the issue:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
/* display none until init */
.owl-carousel{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight{
    -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item{
    float: left;
}
.owl-controls .owl-page,
.owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.owl-controls {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
/* mouse grab icon */
.grabbing { 
}
/* fix */
.owl-carousel  .owl-wrapper,
.owl-carousel  .owl-item{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
/* 
 *  Owl Carousel CSS3 Transitions 
 *  v1.3.2
 */
.owl-origin {
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-x : 50%;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-y : 50%;
    -moz-perspective : 1200px;
    -moz-perspective-origin-x : 50%;
    -moz-perspective-origin-y : 50%;
    perspective : 1200px;
}
/* fade */
.owl-fade-out {
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut .7s both ease;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut .7s both ease;
  animation: fadeOut .7s both ease;
}
.owl-fade-in {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .7s both ease;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn .7s both ease;
  animation: fadeIn .7s both ease;
}
/* backSlide */
.owl-backSlide-out {
  -webkit-animation: backSlideOut 1s both ease;
  -moz-animation: backSlideOut 1s both ease;
  animation: backSlideOut 1s both ease;
}
.owl-backSlide-in {
  -webkit-animation: backSlideIn 1s both ease;
  -moz-animation: backSlideIn 1s both ease;
  animation: backSlideIn 1s both ease;
}
/* goDown */
.owl-goDown-out {
  -webkit-animation: scaleToFade .7s ease both;
  -moz-animation: scaleToFade .7s ease both;
  animation: scaleToFade .7s ease both;
}
.owl-goDown-in {
  -webkit-animation: goDown .6s ease both;
  -moz-animation: goDown .6s ease both;
  animation: goDown .6s ease both;
}
/* scaleUp */
.owl-fadeUp-in {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUpFrom .5s ease both;
  -moz-animation: scaleUpFrom .5s ease both;
  animation: scaleUpFrom .5s ease both;
}
.owl-fadeUp-out {
  -webkit-animation: scaleUpTo .5s ease both;
  -moz-animation: scaleUpTo .5s ease both;
  animation: scaleUpTo .5s ease both;
}
/* Keyframes */
/*empty*/
@-webkit-keyframes empty {
  0% {opacity: 1}
}
@-moz-keyframes empty {
  0% {opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes empty {
  0% {opacity: 1}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes backSlideOut {
  25% { opacity: .5; -webkit-transform: translateZ(-500px); }
  75% { opacity: .5; -webkit-transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(-200%); }
  100% { opacity: .5; -webkit-transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(-200%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes backSlideOut {
  25% { opacity: .5; -moz-transform: translateZ(-500px); }
  75% { opacity: .5; -moz-transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(-200%); }
  100% { opacity: .5; -moz-transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(-200%); }
}
@keyframes backSlideOut {
  25% { opacity: .5; transform: translateZ(-500px); }
  75% { opacity: .5; transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(-200%); }
  100% { opacity: .5; transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(-200%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes backSlideIn {
  0%, 25% { opacity: .5; -webkit-transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(200%); }
  75% { opacity: .5; -webkit-transform: translateZ(-500px); }
  100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes backSlideIn {
  0%, 25% { opacity: .5; -moz-transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(200%); }
  75% { opacity: .5; -moz-transform: translateZ(-500px); }
  100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0); }
}
@keyframes backSlideIn {
  0%, 25% { opacity: .5; transform: translateZ(-500px) translateX(200%); }
  75% { opacity: .5; transform: translateZ(-500px); }
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleToFade {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(.8); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scaleToFade {
  to { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(.8); }
}
@keyframes scaleToFade {
  to { opacity: 0; transform: scale(.8); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes goDown {
  from { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes goDown {
  from { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes goDown {
  from { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleUpFrom {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scaleUpFrom {
  from { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(1.5); }
}
@keyframes scaleUpFrom {
  from { opacity: 0; transform: scale(1.5); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleUpTo {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scaleUpTo {
  to { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(1.5); }
}
@keyframes scaleUpTo {
  to { opacity: 0; transform: scale(1.5); }
}
```

Is there anything within this snippet that causes the carousel disappear when you view the carousel on a mobile device? I can't seem to identify the issue regardless of the fact that i have used the web inspector to locate the issue.

Comment: Please create working jsfiddle, we cannot do anything with just css, as far I can tell it can be js issue too.

Comment: I have sent you a link to the page through your website's contact page. Btw, you have a pretty awesome site.

Comment: thank you very much :) . I was looking at your website and ".donate .hashtag class become display: none; but it's not final issue i guess. I cant check js cuz its minifyed, but I think its breakpoints owlcarousel problem, because on .owl-item .item is set by js height :0; when you will switch it for some height lets say 200px you can see carousel. So i bet its setting js problem

Comment: I sent you a copy of my .js file, its pretty lengthy, but i formatted it for you so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer comes a bit late, but I just encountered the same issue in a browser that uses a version older than CSS3:
if your owl-item is an image,
remove "-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;" from ".owl-carousel .owl-item img" in file owl.carousel.css